# How to get percentage of 2 column total counts per day?

Tags: sql, hadoop

I have the following query:

```
SELECT ACCT_OT, 

COUNT(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%0%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS new,

COUNT(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%1%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS old,

FROM MSTR_TBL where ACCT_OT between '2017-10-23' and '2017-10-25'

GROUP BY ACCT_OT;
```

I want to be able to add another column on the same query where it shows the percentage of old/new. For example on 10/23, new is 10, old is 1, then the third column will be 10%. Hoping you guys can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write your query using `sum()` instead of `count()`:

```
SELECT ACCT_OT, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%0%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS new,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%1%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS old
FROM MSTR_TBL 
WHERE ACCT_OT BETWEEN '2017-10-23' ND '2017-10-25'
GROUP BY ACCT_OT;
```

If you want the *percent* old, I would do:

```
SELECT ACCT_OT, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%0%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS new,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%1%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS old,
       AVG(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%1%' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) AS old
FROM MSTR_TBL 
WHERE ACCT_OT BETWEEN '2017-10-23' ND '2017-10-25'
GROUP BY ACCT_OT;
```

However, the ratio requires repeating the expressions:

```
SELECT ACCT_OT, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%0%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS new,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%1%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS old,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%1%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /
        SUM(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%0%' THEN 1 END)
       ) as ratio
```

I removed the `else 0` to avoid divide-by-zero.

Comment: I tried the percent old..it worked. It gave me decimal for percent but that's sufficient. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using common table expressions. Something like this:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT ACCT_OT, 

    COUNT(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%0%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS new,

    COUNT(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%1%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS old,

    FROM MSTR_TBL where ACCT_OT between '2017-10-23' and '2017-10-25'

    GROUP BY ACCT_OT;
)
SELECT ACCT_OT, new, old, ((old/new) * 100) AS per FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works, because I cannot Test it, but you could try.

`SELECT ACCT_OT, COUNT(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%0%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS new, COUNT(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%1%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS old, 
CONVERT(VARCHSR(50), COUNT(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%1%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) * 100 / COUNT(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%0%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))+'% ' as percentage FROM MSTR_TBL where ACCT_OT between '2017-10-23' and '2017-10-25' GROUP BY ACCT_OT;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
WITH v_mstr_tbl
AS
(SELECT  ACCT_OT, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%0%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS new,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN BR_CD like '%1%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS old
 FROM   MSTR_TBL where ACCT_OT between '2017-10-23' and '2017-10-25'
 GROUP BY ACCT_OT
 )
 SELECT ACCT_OT, new, old, (new/old) * 100 AS percent
   FROM v_mstr_tbl;
```